# read line by `for` loop and rewrtie, creates more rows by spliting them by comma

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I re-upload question after some editing.

This file consists of one column and 81,021 rows.

What I am trying to do is read each row then rewrite files.

After reading each row, I want to count the number of letters, number of special characters, and white spaces and each row.

First, here is my code to read, count number of letters, and rewrite.

```
file = "C:/" # File I want to read
with open("C:/",'w',encoding='cp949',newline='') as testfile: # New file
    csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
    with open(file,'r') as fi:
            for each in fi:
                file=each
                linecount=count_letters(file)
                lst=[file]+[linecount]
                csv_writer.writerow(lst)
```

The problem here is that number of rows increased from 81021 to 86000. Records that have `,` were separated into multiple rows. Here's how I edited.

```
input_fileName = "" 
output_fileName = "" 

f = open(input_fileName, 'r')
out_list = []
buf = ''
flg = 0
for line in f:
    if line.count('"')%2 == 1:
        if flg == 0: flg = 1
        else: flg = 0
    if flg == 1: buf += line.strip(' \n')
    elif flg == 0 and len(buf) > 0:
        buf += line.strip(' \n')
        buf = buf.strip(' "')
        out_list.append([buf,len(buf)])
        buf = ''
    else:
        line = line.strip(' \n')
        out_list.append([line,len(line)])
f.close()

of = open(output_fileName, 'w')
for each in out_list:
    print(each[0]+','+str(each[1]), file=of)
of.close()
```

In this case, a number of rows are not changed.

But now those files creates more columns and records are now separated into multiple columns instead of rows.

How should I fix this problem?

I can't delete `,` in my file since some rows have `,`

---

That one where it says Nationality caused an error. There were both Korean and English written in one cell. There was a line between those two words.

`국적
Nationality`

`성별`

`합계`

And now it turned into 4 rows and there are quotation marks.

`"국적`

`Nationality"`

`성별`

`합계`

Comment: Please provide some sample of your input file.

Comment: @stamaimer How do I upload file? Or do you want image?

Comment: You open the output file with an encoding parameter, but the input file is opened without encoding parameter. Why is it so? Also, why don't you use the csv module to read the file?

Comment: @Gribouillis I had to download files from URL and made them into one file. In that process, some files had different unicode so I put it that way. If I use CSV mudle to read the file, does it work with the file foramt I have? I'm new to Python.

Comment: If you concatenated files with different encodings, the input file may be corrupted and it could very well be the reason for your problems. The solution is to rewrite the input file differently.

Comment: @Gribouillis So you are saying that I should read and write file in cp949 ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you downloaded files having several different encodings and if you concatenated these files in order to create the input file, then you may have a broken input file and there is no good way to read it. What you could do is open each of the downloaded files and decode it with the proper encoding, then rewrite it with a common encoding such as cp949. With these reencoded files, you can create a readable input file.

Comment: @Gribouillis While downloading files, some of them had error so I downloaded them with uft8 and others are downloaded with cp949. What you are saying is that I need to download all the files again right? That's going to take a lot of time to do all the works again... Deadline is tomorrow so I should maybe fix the file manually.

Comment: I don't understand *I downloaded them with uft8*. When you download a file, normally, you don't have to choose an encoding, do you?

Comment: @Gribouillis Yes. But in this case, there were errors depedning on encoding of the file so I used `if` and `else`.

Comment: @Gribouillis If I were to add counting number of ' ' (white space), how can I do this?

Comment: That's a different question, you could perhaps start a new thread and explain precisely what you want to do, but I doubt there is a way to blindly repair a corrupted file without knowing exactly how the data was created and at least what he contents of the file is as @stamaimer asked above.